# Need to copy file from one path to another path

Tags: linux, files, scripting

need to copy file form one path A to another path B and then want to delete the original file form path A .with Linux  script

Comment: Is copying a necessity? Moving `mv` does what you describe, but on the same partition that just means rewriting the pointers, for cross-partition moves, it behaves exactly as you describe: 1) copy file 2) delete original. (you can see this when using the `-v` option for more verbosity)

Comment: Is there some particular restriction or requirement that you're unsure of how to achieve? Otherwise, `mv pathA pathB` seems to do what you ask for, assuming `pathA` is the pathname of the original file and `pathB` is the pathname that you want to move the file to, or of a destination directory.

Answer (score 1):

try using `rsync`:

```
rsync --dry-run -v --remove-source-files /path/A/fileA /path/B/
```

`--dry-run` is used for dry run.